# Automagically Wrapping SQLAlchemy Queries for Causal Historical Simulations

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an event based system which runs in two modes, 1) real time mode 2) historical simulation mode.

All of the event based objects in the ORM have a datetime field indicating the time at which the record was inserted into the DB, ie:

```
class AccountFieldRecord(Base):
    datetime = db.Column(DateTime)
    field_name = db.Column(String(128))
    field_value = db.Column(Numeric)
    ...
```

I'd like to be able to run historical replays off of the DB using exactly the same code I have for the real-time system (which is naturally causal), the only difference being the setup of the data feed to be historical. However, the real-time code has sqlalchemy queries like:

```
past_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(days=5)

records = session.query(AccountFieldRecord).\
    filter(AccountFieldRecord.field_name == 'commission').\
    filter(AccountFieldRecord.datetime >= past_date)
```

Which would clearly allow the system to peak into the future in historical mode as the db has the full history, both past and future relative to the simulation.

So in order to enforce 'causality' in a historical simulation (ie: that the actors in the simulation can't accidentally peak into the future) while keeping the same code I would need to somehow 'wrap' SQLAlchemy to automagically add a filter (with the aid of a simulation timekeeper object):

```
.filter(ORMModel.datetime <= mytimekeeper.timenow())
```

to any causality sensitive queries when the system is in historical sim mode.

In my system code I would like the mode switching to be as simple as defining a custom session factory which takes a parameter indicating run mode (realtime or sim) or something equivalently simple, ie:

```
def my_casual_session_maker(hist_mode=False):
    session = create_session_the_normal_way()
    if hist_mode:
        return MyCausalHistoricalSession(session, mytimekeeper)
    else:
        return session
```

Is there any natural way to accomplish this or something morally equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

This is described in the [PreFilteredQuery Recipe](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/PreFilteredQuery):

```
class DatetimePreFilteredQuery(Query):
    def get(self, ident):
        # override get() so that the flag is always checked in the
        # DB as opposed to pulling from the identity map. - this is optional.
        return Query.get(self.populate_existing(), ident)

    def __iter__(self):
        return Query.__iter__(self.private())

    def from_self(self, *ent):
        # override from_self() to automatically apply
        # the criterion too.   this works with count() and
        # others.
        return Query.from_self(self.private(), *ent)

    def private(self):
        mzero = self._mapper_zero()
        if mzero is not None:
            crit = mzero.class_.datetime <= mytimekeeper.timenow()

            return self.enable_assertions(False).filter(crit)
        else:
            return self
```

To apply it at session creation time based on a flag:

```
def get_session(hist_mode=False):
    if hist_mode:
        return Session(bind=engine, query_cls=DatetimePreFilteredQuery)
    else:
        return Session(bind=engine)
```